# xcatprobe xcatmn fails on IP doesn't belong to any network defined in 'networks' table

Tags: linux, rhel

Im using XCAT management tool to manage my cluster.

Its XCAT version 2.16.5 and the operating system is AlmaLinux 8.7

Its been running without issues for more than a year.

For some reason running `xcatprobe xcatmn -i ens192` , which suppose to check if xCAT has been installed correctly and is ready for use, fails.

The error states as follow :

> IP 10.1.100.80 of ens192 doesn't belong to any network defined in 'networks' table.

[image: xcatprobe xcatmnError message]

this is my networks table :

```
#netname,net,mask,mgtifname,gateway,dhcpserver,tftpserver,nameservers,ntpservers,logservers,dynamicrange,staticrange,staticrangeincrement,nodehostname,ddnsdomain,vlanid,domain,mtu,comments,disable
"net10","10.0.0.0/8","255.0.0.0","ens192","10.1.1.1",,"<xcatmaster>","10.100.100.101,10.100.100.102",,"10.10.5.4","10.0.0.1-10.255.255.255",,,,,,"phys.local","1500",,
```

As far as i know 10.1.100.80 is part of 10.0.0.0/8

Running `ip addr show ens192` :

[image]

Im not sure where to start looking

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks to be because you are defining your `net` as `10.0.0.0/8`, but xCAT is wanting the [network address](https://xcat-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/admin-guides/references/man5/networks.5.html), which is `10.0.0.0`.

The network address, `net`, combined with the mask, `255.0.0.0`, will allow xCAT to determine the full scope is `10.0.0.0/8`.

Comment: I tried both ways, with and without the /net. it failed as well